# JTS Polygon.intersects() returns false even though the two polygons touch eachother

Tags: java, intersection, jts

I'm trying to check if two polygons are next to each other and touch eachother. For that purpose I use the method ".intersects()" from the JTS library but it returns false even though visually the two polygons touch eachother.
Here is my code that I test the two polygons. (Keep in mind this is only for testing purposes and the actual code will be rewritten.)

```
    String testCoords1 = "M149.9 373.5l-3-3.4-9.4-7.2-5-2-0.7-7.6-1.1-4.1-1.7-3.6-3.3-1.7-2.8-2.3-3.8-3.8-4.2-2.8 5-6.3 6.7-0.7 3.3 2.3 3.8 0.6 2.8-1.6 2.4-2.9 0.4-4.3-2-3.9 7.8-6.5 0.2-10 3.8-7.6 2.5 1 2 2.4 8 5.3 7.7 2.2 8-3.4 7.3-1.6 6.2 5.7 6 0.4 5.7-4-2 5.7-3.3 6.2-8.6 19-3 13.3 2.4 4.7 6.8 16.5 8.4 14.9 5 4.8 1.6 7.2-4 4.1-4.5-2-6.7 1.1-4.3-2.9 1.8-7.1-3.2-6-1.1-3.7 0-2.6-6.5-1.4-3 6.3-4 6.2-5.7-1.4-5.7-4.5-13-7z";
    String testCoords2 = "M114.9 335l4.2 2.8 3.8 3.8 2.8 2.3 3.3 1.7 1.7 3.6 1.1 4.1 0.7 7.6 5 2 9.4 7.2 3 3.4-5.4 8.2-3.6 9.7 1.7 9.4-2.1 3.2-0.7 3.9-4.4 0.6-4.2-2.3-4.8-0.8-4.6-4-2 5.9-2.7 0.4-3-2-8.6-2.9-3.6 1-9.6 0.8-6.4 5.3-4.4 0.8-3.7-2.3-2.7-4.6-3.5-3.5-3.6-2.2-2.5-4.1-3.3-4.1-2.5-3.8 0.5-6.9-2.8-4.2-4.7 1.4-2.7-3.2-0.6-4.5-2.8-2.9-3-5.2-2.1-6.2-4.9-2.6-6 0.6-7.8-1.2-6.4 0.5 1.2-7.6-1.1-3 4.1-7.9 2.2-2.1 0-2.6-2.4-1.9-2.2-3.3-3.8-9.2-0.3-1.7 1.5-2.3 1.4-1.3 4.1-2.1 1.7-1.5 2.4-3.8 1.5-1.3 5 0.4 2-1.9 2.2-1.5 4.3-0.6 12 3.3 4.9-1.2 4.8-2.1 2-2.6 4.4 4 2.7 4.3 0.9 2.7 1.4 2 1.5-0.2 1.2 1.1 2.6-0.5 2.2-3.9 2.3 1.3-1 6.9 3.2 2.2 3.9-2.4 3.1 3.8 2.7 5.4 4.9 0 1.7 2.9 3 0.7 4.8-0.7 3.1 5 2.4 6.5z";

    GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory();
    ArrayList<Coordinate> coordinatesShape1 = calcGeo(testCoords1);
    ArrayList<Coordinate> coordinatesShape2 = calcGeo(testCoords2);

    Polygon poly1 = geometryFactory.createPolygon(coordinatesShape1.toArray(new Coordinate[] {}));
    boolean valid = poly1.isValid();
    System.out.println(valid);

    Polygon poly2 = geometryFactory.createPolygon(coordinatesShape2.toArray(new Coordinate[] {}));
    boolean valid2 = poly2.isValid();
    System.out.println(valid2);

    boolean intersects = poly1.intersects(poly2);
    System.out.println(intersects);
```

This is the code for calcGeo() method that I use to seperate the coordinates and save them in an ArrayList (This will be rewritten as well)

```
private ArrayList<Coordinate> calcGeo(String coords)
{
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\([mzlhvcsqta]|[\\+\\-]?(\\d*\\.\\d+|\\d+\\.?)([eE][\\+\\-]?\\d+)*");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(coords);
    double X = 0;
    double Y = 0;
    int index = 0;
    ArrayList<Coordinate> points = new ArrayList<>();

    while(m.find()) {
        //System.out.println(m.group());
        switch (index)
        {
            case 0: X = Double.parseDouble(m.group()); break;
            case 1: Y = Double.parseDouble(m.group()); break;
        }
        if (index % 2 == 0 && index != 0)
        {
            double calcX = X + Double.parseDouble(m.group());
            //System.out.println(calcX);
            X = calcX;
        }else if(index % 2 == 1 && index != 1)
        {
            double calcY = Y + Double.parseDouble(m.group());
            //System.out.println(calcY);
            Y = calcY;
        }
        if (index % 2 == 1)
        {
            points.add(new Coordinate(X, Y)); //Add the coords to the list every second time so both X and Y are calculated.
        }
        index++;
    }
    points.add(points.get(0));  //After all the points are mapped complete the polygon by adding the first pair of coords to the end of the list.
    return points;
}
```

Basically I have two Strings with SVG data coordinates which I pass to calcGeo method so I can extract only the coordinates.
Then I save those to two ArrayLists and with those I construct the two polygons and check if they are valid.
For those two exact polygons".intersects()" is returning "false" but clearly they touch each other(see the image).
[The two coordiante paths visualized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgHVu.png)

Is this the right approach for me to check if two polygons are next to each other and touch ?
If it is how could I fix this bug ? If not whats the best approach to check that ?

Comment: Yeah, maybe I'm misunderstanding the use if .intersects() method. I'd like just to check if polygon one touches polygon two.

Comment: I'll leave the answers to the JTS experts, but this strikes me as a very traditional definition of "intersects."  `{1, 2, 3}` and `{4, 5, 6}` touch, but have no intersection.  The edges of polygons are *notoriously* difficult to get right in numerical algorithms.  3d graphics people spend a great amount of care ensuring their models don't have patterns like T junctions which lead to numerical instability in the rendering.